# Reduce string length by removing contiguous duplicates

Tags: string, r, dataframe, dimensionality-reduction

I have an R dataframe whith 2 fields:

```
ID             WORD
1           AAAAABBBBB
2           ABCAAABBBDDD
3           ...
```

I'd like to simplify the words with repeating letters by keeping only the letter and not the duplicates in a repetition:

e.g.: `AAAAABBBBB` should give me `AB`
and   `ABCAAABBBDDD` should give me `ABCABD`

Anyone has an idea on how to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's a solution with regex:

```
x <- c('AAAAABBBBB', 'ABCAAABBBDDD')
gsub("([A-Za-z])\\1+","\\1",x)
```

EDIT: By request, some benchmarking. I added Matthew Lundberg's pattern in the comment, matching any character. It appears that `gsub` is faster by an order of magnitude, and matching any character is faster than matching letters.

```
library(microbenchmark)
set.seed(1)
##create sample dataset
x <- apply(
  replicate(100,sample(c(LETTERS[1:3],""),10,replace=TRUE))
,2,paste0,collapse="")
##benchmark
xm <- microbenchmark(
    SAPPLY = sapply(strsplit(x, ''), function(x) paste0(rle(x)$values, collapse=''))
    ,GSUB.LETTER = gsub("([A-Za-z])\\1+","\\1",x)
    ,GSUB.ANY = gsub("(.)\\1+","\\1",x)
)
##print results
print(xm)
# Unit: milliseconds
         # expr       min        lq    median        uq       max
# 1    GSUB.ANY  1.433873  1.509215  1.562193  1.664664  3.324195
# 2 GSUB.LETTER  1.940916  2.059521  2.108831  2.227435  3.118152
# 3      SAPPLY 64.786782 67.519976 68.929285 71.164052 77.261952

##boxplot of times
boxplot(xm)
##plot with ggplot2
library(ggplot2)
qplot(y=time, data=xm, colour=expr) + scale_y_log10()
```

Comment: You can replace `[A-Za-z]` with `.` here.

Answer (score 4):

```
x <- c('AAAAABBBBB', 'ABCAAABBBDDD')
sapply(strsplit(x, ''), function(x) paste0(rle(x)$values, collapse=''))
## [1] "AB"     "ABCABD"
```

Comment: :) That is _literally_, character for character, what I had just copy+pasted over as an answer.

Comment: So, time challenge:  is `sapply` or `gsub` faster here?