# R remove special character and repeating underscores

Tags: r, regex

I have a dataset that contains spaces and other punctuation characters.  I'm trying to replace the spaces and special characters with "_".  This creates spots with multiple "_" strung together, so I'd like to remove these too by using the following function as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14159364/reduce-string-length-by-removing-contiguous-duplicates) :

```
removeSpace <- function(x){
    class1 <- class(x)
    x <- as.character(x)
    x <- gsub(" |&|-|/|'|(|)",'_', x) # convert special characters to _
    x <- gsub("([_])\\1+","\\1", x)   # convert multiple _ to single _

    if(class1 == 'character'){
        return(x)
    }
    if(class1 == 'factor'){
        return(as.factor(x))
    }
}
```

The issue is instead of removing spaces and replacing with "_" it does every other character with "_" (i.e. "test" -> "t_e_s_t")

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You don't need to run two separate replacements to accomplish this. Just put a `+` quantifier in your match pattern.

Match: `[-/&'() ]+`

Replace with: `_`

Also note that I used a character set instead of switching between each option with `|`. This is generally a better approach when matching one of multiple individual characters.

Comment: +1. But I would have also added an `_`(underscore) in that character set. So, that the 2nd `gsub` is not required at all. What do you think?

Comment: @Gurman I suppose that wouldn't hurt, but the OP only indicated that they needed the second replacement due to an undesired outcome of their first replacement. As I understood the question, multiple `_`s were not a problem in the original string. @screechOwl Do you think this would be useful?

Comment: I ended up using this : `x <- gsub("[[:punct:]]+",'_', x)`.  Thanks for the `+` idea.